# Making a backup of the structure and a limited number of records of each table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a SQL server database with huge tables.
I want this database to be automatically backed up every day.
Usually the backup is also heavy.
So, I want only the structure to be backed up and also the number of 1000 records from each table to be considered in the backup.
So I want to backup the structure and 1000 records of each table.
Is there a way for my problem?

Consider that I do not want a full backup.
Consider that I don't want a backup of the structure(only).

Comment: There is no such built-in feature for this. If you want to a backup of your structure, then you are far better off with a database project in a source control environment, and ensuring that the data (in your source control software) is backed up. For having "1000 rows", this honestly could easily not work; if you have any key relationships then your (arbitrary) 1000 rows could fail your `CONSTRAINTS`, making the data useless. Perhaps what you actually need is a development environment, with a much smaller (and obviously not real) set of data.

Comment: If you have foreign key relationship between table, backup will not be useful

Comment: `DBCC CLONEDATABASE` can make a schema-only copy, but filling it is still something you have to do yourself. As others have pointed out, this is not entirely trivial of you want usable results, and even the `CLONEDATABASE` is arguably inferior to building the database from (source-controlled) scripts (though more resistant to growing stale if ad-hoc schema deployments are policy in your environment, which they unfortunately still often are).

Comment: ...you _do_ know how differential backups work, right?

Comment: I'm curious - what purpose would such a backup serve? This feels like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)